# Which is the best method for efficiency/less work load on server

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I am curious to know what would be the preferred method for a table which would store a list of IDs associated with a UserID.

Should I have one field storing a serialized array of all the id's (one row per UserID)

Or one row for every id for every player? Is the answer clear cut or are there factors to take into account when making such a decision?

Hope you can help explain the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're going to get the whole list of IDs everytime or most of the time, or if the lists of IDs are short, then serializing them is fine (though I wouldn't recommend it anyway)

However you'll be missing out on indexing if you ever need to search for a user using an ID in the list of IDs as a constraint.

Best way is to have a separate table storing the many-to-many relations (which is what I'm assuming you want). If you have a one-to-many relationship, then you should reverse the way that you are referencing the relation and add a user_id column to the table containing the IDs .

Comment: my concern is that the row count is going to be hitting the million+ pretty quickly..

Comment: then it's actually better to put it in a separate table

Comment: @Dave million+ is a very small number in the database world. Populus's answer contains good suggestions - listen to them.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep one row for every id for every player. That to me is more manageable and clean approach. How many records are you looking at here though ?

Comment: what type of operations would you perform on the data?

Comment: mainly listing to see if the id exists for that user (such as in_array() ) if it was serialized method

Comment: definitely sepearate table then, don't do in_array(), use SQL to filter out the results... SQL is optimized for going through massive amounts of data whereas PHP is not.